# Variadic template: Perfect forwarding of integer parameter to lambda

Tags: c++, c++14

There are similar questions, but I did not find an answer that works for my problem.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

class TestClass
{
public:
   TestClass( int value): mValue( value) { }
private:
   int  mValue;
};

template< typename T> class DeferredCreator
{
public:
   template< class... Args> DeferredCreator( Args&&... args):
      mpCreator( [=]() -> T*
         { return new T( std::forward< Args>( args)...);  }
      ),
      mpObject()
   { }

   T* get() {
      if (mpObject == nullptr)
         mpObject.reset( mpCreator());
      return mpObject.get();
   }
private:
   std::function< T*( void)>  mpCreator;
   std::unique_ptr< T>        mpObject;
};


int main() {
   DeferredCreator< int>  dcInt( 42);

   assert( dcInt.get() != nullptr);
   return 0;
}
```

The idea is that the class DeferredCreator creates an object only when it is really needed. I got this work e.g. for strings, but I can't figure out how to pass a simple integer into my lambda.

The error message I get is:

```
prog.cpp:19:26: error: no matching function for call to 'forward'
         { return new T( std::forward< Args>( args)...);  }
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cpp:36:27: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'DeferredCreator<int>::DeferredCreator<int>' requested here
   DeferredCreator< int>  dcInt( 42);
                          ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.3.0/../../../../include/c++/6.3.0/bits/move.h:76:5: note: candidate function not viable: 1st argument ('const int') would lose const qualifier
    forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type& __t) noexcept
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.3.0/../../../../include/c++/6.3.0/bits/move.h:87:5: note: candidate function not viable: 1st argument ('const int') would lose const qualifier
    forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&& __t) noexcept
    ^
2 errors generated.
```

I already tried to use `decltype( args)` as template argument for `std::forward<>`, but that did not help.

The code is also available here: https://ideone.com/MIhMkt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `operator()` of the *closure type* generated by your *lambda expression* is `const`-qualified. `std::forward` can attempt to move `args...`, which are data members of the closure. `const` objects cannot be moved.

You can mark your lambda as `mutable`:

```
  mpCreator( [=]() mutable -> T*
     { return new T( std::forward< Args>( args)...);  }
  ),
```

This removes the implicit `const` qualfiier from the *closure type*'s generated `operator()`.

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AuRlvSkH2GFM6HWO9)

Comment: Does `forward<Args>(args)...` here actually forward?

Answer (score 8):

`args...` is constant because a lambda's call operator is implicitly `const`. So, if you make your lambda mutable, then it works:

```
[=]() mutable -> T*
     { return new T( std::forward< Args>( args)...);  }
```

The reason it didn't work with `decltype(args)` is that the types themselves are not `const`, just the call operator.